# Find the cheapest flight to reach from source to destination

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, programming-challenge, dijkstra

- As the input you get the flight schedule as an array, each element of which is the price of a direct flight between 2 cities `(an array of 3 elements - 2 city names as a string, and a flight price).`
- Planes fly in both directions and the price in both directions is the same. There is a possibility that there are no direct flights between cities.

Question:

Find the price of the *cheapest flight between cities* that are given as the 2nd and 3rd arguments.

Input:

3 arguments: the flight schedule as an array of arrays, city of departure and destination city.

Output:

Int. The best price.

Example:

```
cheapest_flight([['A', 'C', 100],
  ['A', 'B', 20],
  ['B', 'C', 50]],
 'A',
 'C') == 70
cheapest_flight([['A', 'C', 100],
  ['A', 'B', 20],
  ['B', 'C', 50]],
 'C',
 'A') == 70
```

MyCode:

I am using `Dijkstras Algorithm` to resolve the problem.

Please let me know if this approach can be improved in any way.

```
flights = [['A', 'C', 100],
           ['A' ,'B', 20],
           ['B', 'C', 50]]

src = "A"
dst = "C"

def solution(flights, src, dst):
    from collections import defaultdict
    from queue import PriorityQueue
    
    graph = defaultdict(dict)
    for s,d,w in flights:
        graph[s][d] = w
        
    pq = PriorityQueue()
    pq.put((0, src))
    
    vis = set()
    
    while pq:
        minCost, dest = pq.get()
        if dest == dst: return minCost
        
        if dest in vis:
            continue
            
        vis.add(dest)
        
        for y,w in graph[dest].items():
            pq.put((minCost+w, y))
            
    return -1
        
solution(flights, src, dst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: Try `solution(flights, "C", "A")`
(Part of this problem: `while pq:` doesn't work as intended - `while not pq.empty():` should be closer.)

---

You present one slick implementation of *Dijkstra's Algorithm*.

This being CR, I think there are possible improvements to details of how it is coded - and one strategic one:

- Stick to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).
  Where deviating (like importing inside a function), have a reason to, maybe document that reason with a comment. Strategically
- [Document your code. In the code.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)
- Naming:
  Name things for their role/purpose, not for their type.
  `costs` rather than `graph`, `cheapest` rather than `pq`.
  As *code is read much more often than it is written*, I'd prefer `visited` over `vis`.
  (And yes, there are variables here that are more difficult to name -
  code the way *you* think about the solution.)
  (I guess I'm inconsistent with this advice when inclined to name the function `dijktra_s()` rather than `shortest_path()`.
  I do detest `solution` - make it an alias where needed.)
- You conditionally don't process some items found cheapest.
  Instead, make insertion conditional - unless evaluating that condition uses more resources than inserting in `cheapest`.
- to have the module usable from outside, put "usage examples" in a
  `if __name__ == "__main__":`
- Separation of concerns:
  I think transforming the `flights` array into a cost graph not to be part of Dijkstra's.
  I didn't come up with a better remedy to the "symmetry problem" mentioned at the start of this post than to add `costs[d][s] = c` (`graph[d][s] = w`) - yet.
- keep introduction of things close to usage, scopes small (even where only conceptual/"visual"):
  e.g., "the global" `flights` close to calls using it
  (When trying to do that with "the global `src`/`dst`", their motivation looks slim)

---

Algorithm:
Cost/distance being symmetrical, *bidirectional Dijkstra's* can be expected to use less resources.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I will make the changes related to documentation and naming convention. Regarding functionality, I have changed `while pq` to `while not pq.empty().` Do you see any other issue functionality wise?

Comment: I have just now noticed that after changing the while loop, `shortest_path(flights, "C", "A")` is returning `-1` which is not correct?

Comment: Should I make two types of entries in the `graph dict?`.   `graph = defaultdict(dict) for s,d,w in flights: graph[s][d] = w` `for s,d,w in flights: graph[d][s] = w `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139745/discussion-between-meallhour-and-greybeard).

Comment: what do you think about adding an if condition inside the for loop? `for neighbor, w in graph[dest].items(): if neighbor not in vis:  pq.put((minCost+w, neighbor))`

Comment: See fourth bullet.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the `queue` library is designed to be thread safe. There is some extra overhead, such as for acquiring a mutex, before many operations. According to the documentation `PriorityQueue` is implemented using the `heapq` library. If thread safety isn't needed, consider using `heapq` directly.